# Remap keys for one specific program under Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, gvim, keymap

How can I set keys to be remapped for one specific program in Linux? (More specifically Caps Lock -> Escape for gVim. I hit it accidentally too much to remap it in everything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Vim's wiki on wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip166).

> If you want to completely swap the
>   Caps Lock and Escape keys, you have to
>   replace the "Lock" on Caps Lock. Drop
>   this file in your home directory:

```
! Swap caps lock and escape
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keysym Escape = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Escape
add Lock = Caps_Lock
```

> and call it ".speedswapper". Then open
>   a terminal and type

```
$ xmodmap .speedswapper
```

> The swapping lasts for the duration of
>   the X session, so you can put it in a
>   .xinitrc or similar startup file.

There are some other [interesting alternative ESC mappings](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key) as well.

Comment: No good. I want it changed for vim only, while this changes it for everything.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to do it inside vim because X catches the key stroke long before vi or vim can see it, that's why the official wiki doesn't have a vimrc approach. You should use an application outside vim that catches caps key on OS level (read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176532/how-to-map-caps-lock-key-in-vim for more information). You can try to use a bash script to turn on/off caps lock key when needed. http://dancingpenguinsoflight.com/2009/01/maps-caps-lock-key-to-escape/

Answer (score 2):

Autokey allows you to remap keys with window filters, and it's available in most distributions' repositories. As a bonus you can even map scripts to certain keypresses, it's pretty powerful. https://code.google.com/p/autokey/

Comment: Maintained of Autokey: https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Installing

Answer (score 1):

you can write a simple bash script which can run the above mentioned solution whenever you run vim and remove the file after you close vlc.